# A monospace or typewriter font with matching math support

Tags: fonts, typewriter

This might sound odd but I really like the old typewriter books from the pre-TeX era (the type of books that inspired Knuth to make TeX!). I don't know the exact reason, maybe its because I am very fond of typewriter and monospace fonts or just a nostalgia for old math books from 1960s ...

Anyway I am looking for typewriter font with matching math support. It is easy to change the text of a document into a typewriter font however the math font never matches and that results in an ugly combination. An example which I really like is  [**Moments, monodromy, and perversity: a diophantine perspective**](http://books.google.ca/books?id=Tp7BN8JAv7AC) by Nick Katz. I contacted the author and unfortunately he has not done this in TeX. The fonts are **bit fonts** created by William Fulton back in the 1980s. So what are your suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

DejaVu Sans Mono have both Latin and Greek plus some math symbols, if you use fontspec and unocode-math then it can be used for simple formulas:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
\(
  \text{Sum}(E, f, ψ) ≔ ∑_{x_1,\dots, x_n \text{in} E} ψ_E(f(x_1,\dots, x_n)).
\)
\end{document}
```

But more complex formulas needs OpenType math tables in the font.

Comment: One should note that this needs XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: Indeed, that was implied. Also, there is Free Mono which have even more math coverage (and Courier look).

Comment: This did not work for me since I have tex-live on Linux.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, you also need texlive-2010 (which is in pretest) for this to work, otherwise you have to update/install all the required pieces yourself, which is quit tricky.

Answer (score 4):

They aren't monospace (neither is the font used in the main text of your example), but I think the [Concrete fonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ccfonts) have a bit of a typewrite look.

Comment: I know about *Concrete* and I understand that the font in Katz's book is not monospace but it is definitely a typewriter font and if you look at my question it says _monospace or typewriter_ font.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the body text to a typewriter font and using [`mathastext`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) will get you some way towards your goal. This won't give you greek letters or things like appropriate integral signs, but it's a start...

Comment: On the other hand that book is ugly, from a typographical point of view.